# Возникает ошибка при написании " ' "

Tags: html

Дано текст:

```
<p>
To'lovni to'lash rejasida, xaridor va sotuvchi o'rtasida savdo shartnomasi asosida ishlaydi, bunda tovarlarning asl narxlari aks ettiriladi va xaridorga oldindan ma'lum bo'lgan qo'shimcha to'lov qo'shiladi.
</p>
```

При написании o' возникает ошибка. Как правильно оформить, чтобы не вылезала ошибка?

Comment: Где и какая ошибка? Вы же здесь вопрос написали, и никакой ошибки Вам не выдало.

Comment: Причём тут **HTML** и ошибки? просто напишите `<span>To'lovni to'lash rejasida, xaridor va sotuvchi o'rtasida savdo shartnomasi asosida ishlaydi, bunda tovarlarning asl narxlari aks ettiriladi va xaridorga oldindan ma'lum bo'lgan qo'shimcha to'lov qo'shiladi.</span>`. У меня лично всё работает.

Comment: <p> текст все нормально, как только верхнюю кавычку после o' текст </p>  высвечивается после него. Я понимаю что это связано с (" ' ") как правильно её оформить, чтобы она была в тексте?

Comment: @RinatGataullin а вы можете свой код пожалуйста показать полностью, дополните его в вопрос.

Comment: Судя по Вашей специализации, ошибку Вам выдаёт Python (html не может в принципе выдавать никаких ошибок). Возможно, дело в необходимости экранирования специальных символов. Пишите перед одинарной кавычкой обратный слеш \'

Answer (score 1):

Суть вопроса неясна, но могу предположить, что всё дело в экранировании одинарной кавычки. Например, вот такая попытка вывести в консоль строку вызовет ошибку:

```js
console.log('To'lovni to'lash rejasida');
```

Чтобы ошибки не возникало, одинарные кавычки внутри строки необходимо экранировать обратным слешем:

```js
console.log('To\'lovni to\'lash rejasida');
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, в чём ваша ошибка. Если у вас код такой, то у вас не должно быть ошибки, а отображаться должно правильно.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>New Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>To'lovni to'lash rejasida, xaridor va sotuvchi o'rtasida savdo shartnomasi asosida ishlaydi, bunda tovarlarning asl narxlari aks ettiriladi va xaridorga oldindan ma'lum bo'lgan qo'shimcha to'lov qo'shiladi.</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы сталкиваете с "ошибкой" которую подсвечивает "подсветка синтаксиса", но это только ошибка в самой подсветке.
Там где используется подсветка *нормальная* подсветка не отображает что что-то не так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если всё же боитесь ошибки, то экранируйте эти символы - `\'`